# Log4j - Looking for a good 'Getting started' tutorial or blog

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I downloaded Log4j version 1.2.16 today.   I want to enable logging in a simple java console application.   I'm looking for a 'quick start' tutorial or blog that allows me to perform file logging with some good code samples.

Comment: Try [this](http://www.developer.com/open/article.php/10930_3097221_1) step by step intro.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [short introduction to log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html) is a perfectly fine starting point for log4j.

If you're ready to spend some money, you can buy the [log4j manual](http://www.qos.ch/shop/products/log4jManual).

By the way, if you're new to logging in Java, I'd suggest the [slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org/) + [logback](http://logback.qos.ch/index.html) combo. In my opinion, this is the best logging solution available. Slf4j is a logging "facade" and it needs an implementation underneath. Log4j and logback can be used as implementations.

Since logback is log4j's successor and made by the same author, I'd suggest using it instead. Not only that, logback's manual is available [online](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/index.html) and it's free.

Since log4j's development has more or less stalled, I'd suggest you upgrade to slf4j + logback.

Comment: don't forget, that Log4J is still mainly used in corporate environments as a logging framework.

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman: True. I'd suggest upgrading to slf4j + logback only if that option is feasible.

Comment: If only every corporation was aware of the answer to this question.

Answer (score 2):

Please see whether this ["How to integrate log4j with Java project"](http://www.digizol.com/2013/10/log4j-how-to-integrate-with-your-java.html) helps you. It takes you through 5 quick steps.

- Set up the project with log4j
- Create log4j.properties file
- Write a class to record log messages
- Compile and run program
- Check the log messages

Even though the question is older, as you have asked for a tutorial or a blog post on how to get started quickly, I thought of sharing this.