# Application is not logging log, how to debug log 4j starting or not

Tags: java, log4j

I have created a very simple application, where I am trying to use the Log4J, but my application is not logging any log.

Can anyone please tell me how can I debug the same as my log4j started or not?

I have kept the file in classes folder of `WEB-INF/classes`

Thanks

following is my log4j.properties

```
log4j.rootLogger=debug, stdout, ABC

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

# Pattern to output the caller's file name and line number.
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n

log4j.appender.ABC=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.ABC.File=D://abc//dams_workflow_application.log

log4j.appender.ABC.MaxFileSize=3000KB
# Keep one backup file
log4j.appender.ABC.MaxBackupIndex=10

log4j.appender.ABC.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.ABC.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n
```

following is the sample line for using log 4j..

```
 Logger log = Logger.getLogger("ABC");
 log.info("my message");
```

Comment: You may want to post the code you use to init your log4j

Comment: You say you use web-inf/classes - does that mean that you are running a WAR inside a container- tomcat, jetty whatsoever? Who is responsible for your log4j configuration startup - your application or the container itself?

Answer (score 1):

If you're writing a web application, you can view the [Log4J Default Initialization Under Tomcat](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html). Even it states Tomcat, the same applies in other Containers/Web application servers.

Answer (score 0):

Console will print this if log4j is not started :

```
log4j:WARN No log4j configuration information found.
log4j:WARN Changed non-configured level from DEBUG to ERROR.
log4j:WARN The log4j system is not properly configured!
```

You could have a look at [Log4j - Looking for a good 'Getting started' tutorial or blog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370282/log4j-looking-for-a-good-getting-started-tutorial-or-blog)
to get started.

Regards,
 Stéphane

Comment: Thanks, I am not getting any message I have updated the log property file also

Comment: You have to follow instructions specific to your servlet container.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the log4j jar is in the lib directory for your webapp or in the lib directory in tomcat.
Log4j doesn't seem to work properly for me unless i put the log4j properties file in the default package in the webapp's source directory within the project.

All of  my log4j properties files typically look similar to the following

```
# Define a logger called "processLog" using the FileAppender implementation of the
# Log interface
log4j.appender.processLog=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.processLog.File.DateFormat='.'yyyy-ww

# Define the output location
log4j.appender.processLog.File=C:/logs/myapp.log

# Define what the output is going to look like for your log
log4j.appender.processLog.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.processLog.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a} %5p %c{1}: Line#%L - %m%n

# log4j.rootLogger specifies the default logging level and output location.
# The first parameter is the level (debug > info > warn > error > fatal).
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, processLog
```

That's how I do it anyway. There may be a better way but this one always works for me.