# Installing Log4J 2 on Windows 10

Tags: windows, log4j, installation

I am trying to install log4j (2) on Windows 10. I downloaded and extracted log4j from https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/download.html

However I don't know what do add to the path variable or how to call log4j on windows 10.

The latest steps on Linux for log4j where:

```
$ export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/local/apache-log4j-1.2.15/log4j-1.2.15.jar
$ export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/apache-log4j-1.2.15/
```

The Problem here is, as far as I know, Windows has no `classpath` and there is no `log4j.jar` file just `log4j-core` and `log4j-api` (and similar) jars.

If someone could help me set this up correctly I'd greatly appreciate this.

Answer (score 1):

Log4j does not require installation. It is a set of libraries. You should not specify the `CLASSPATH` as a system-wide environment variable (however it is acceptable). If you want your application make use of log4j you should propagate the class path to log4j libraries as [a parameter to java.exe](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html). If you need those libs on development phase you should either specify the path in your IDE project settings (the way how to do this is specific for each particular IDE), or, if you use standard `maven` project type, specify the appropriate dependency in `pom` file so that IDE takes care of proper classpath configuration.

Please also refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370282/log4j-looking-for-a-good-getting-started-tutorial-or-blog) helping you to get started with log4j.

Comment: Remember when Log4j ruined the internet?